# Why is my Docker container still trying to connect to localhost MongoDB in my Flask Microservice?

Tags: mongodb, docker, flask

I have two Docker containers running on the same bridge network (docker0).

- **mongodb** - MongoDB container with my database
- **usercreate** - Create_User API running on flask and inserts user into the MongoDB container.

I am testing in Postman on my local machine to send data to this "usercreate" container which will write into the MongoDB container.

When running my containers, ***usercreate*** was port forwarded with 5000:5000, and ***mongodb*** is 27017:27017 (for testing purposes.)

**All scenarios were executed with Postman**.

**---------Scenario1:**

- localhost:5000/createuser

  ```
  pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
  ```

I have tried all MONGO_URI configs for the mongodb container name, the port, without the port, and with just the container IP.

```
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://mongodb:27017/User"
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://mongodb/User"
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://172.18.0.2:27017/User"
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://172.18.0.2/User"
```

**---------Scenario2:**

I ran this usercreate flask app on my localhost on port 5001 (since 5000 is being used by the usercreate container)

- `localhost:5001/createuser`

Everything worked!

**---------Scenario3:**

When running the containers on the "host" network instead of bridge, the usercreate container worked as well.

---

I am thinking the reason is because my ***usercreate*** container is trying to find the Mongo database in `localhost:27017` instead of `mongodb:27017` as per the error in **Scenario1** (also shown below)

```
 `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused`
```

How do I get the ***usercreate*** container to use the (container name):27017 MONGO_URI instead of localhost:27017? It seems it is ignoring my MONGO_URI in my Flask configuration.

Could there be any other reasons for this error?

Comment: What’s actually using the `app.config["MONGO_URI"]` you’re showing?  Can you add the code that actually connects to MongoDB?

Comment: @DavidMaze after a full night's rest, I realized that I was not actually using this app.config. I did not realized that MongoClient() is defaulted to localhost.

Thank you for the heads up. If you rewrite your comment as an answer, then I'll mark it as answered.